# Kernel parameters are not changed permanently for RHEL7

Tags: linux, rhel, kernel, kernel-parameters

Trying to permanently change some vm kernel parameters, I created `/etc/sysctl.d/01-custom.conf` config file as it described in Red Hat knowledgebase article. Here is its content:

```
# cat /etc/sysctl.d/01-custom.conf
vm.swappiness=10
vm.dirty_ratio=20
vm.vfs_cache_pressure=200
```

But after reboot only `vm.vfs_cache_pressure` is changed and `swappines` and `dirty_ratio` have previous values.

```
# sysctl vm.swappiness
vm.swappiness = 30
# sysctl vm.dirty_ratio
vm.dirty_ratio = 30
```

In `/etc/sysctl.conf` file there is no changes for `vm.dirty_ratio` parameter and `vm.swappines` is set to 10 as well. Does it mean that the system takes these values from somewhere else?
There are no any config files under `/etc/sysctl.d` besides mine and link to `/etc/sysctl.conf`:

```
# ll /etc/sysctl.d/
total 4
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 147 May 30 04:40 01-custom.conf
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root  14 Apr  3 15:00 99-sysctl.conf -> ../sysctl.conf
```

**Update:**
`sysctl --system` shows that values from my config were taken. Nothing for `vm.swappines` and `vm.dirty_ratio` are set to 30.

Comment: If you run `sysctl -p`, will the values you wanted come into effect? If so, it might be that the sysctl settings are applied in initramfs phase of the boot, and you'll just need to rebuild your initramfs to make the changes happen automatically at boot time..

Comment: Several parameters can be achieved from `/lib/sysctl.d/` directory. Maybe your parameters is stored there. All available paths you can get from `man 5 sysctl.conf` in **FILES** section.

Comment: @telcoM, yes, running `sysctl -p` changes values but only till the reboot.

Comment: Thanks @YurijGoncharuk. I've checked all the directories that are listed in `man` for `sysctl.conf` and found out a few more configs - nothing for `swappines` or `dirty_ratio` set to 30. Also, I checked with `sysctl --system` - updated description.

Comment: @telcoM, strange, but rebuilding initramfs didn't help..

Comment: @sys463 I've tested your scenario on CentOS 7.5 and it works. Sorry, but I can't test it on RHEL. I think about another suggestion.

Comment: Are you able to change the kernel parameters at boot via GRUB?

Comment: @jc__, do you mean adding it to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX` in `/etc/default/grub`?

Answer (score 0):

If you are running tuned, it will take precedence over sysctl: [Sysctl.conf parameters overridden by Tuned](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/2733921)

Check if tuned is running:

```
systemctl status tuned
```

If it is running, check which profile is active:

```
tuned-adm active
```

Tuned's profiles can be found in /usr/lib/tuned/:

```
# grep -ri '^vm.swappiness' /usr/lib/tuned/
/usr/lib/tuned/latency-performance/tuned.conf:vm.swappiness=10
/usr/lib/tuned/throughput-performance/tuned.conf:vm.swappiness=10
/usr/lib/tuned/virtual-guest/tuned.conf:vm.swappiness = 30
```

Answer (score 0):

Default /etc/sysctl.conf file on the CentOS 7 server comments that;

> # sysctl settings are defined through files in
>
> # /usr/lib/sysctl.d/, /run/sysctl.d/, and /etc/sysctl.d/.
>
> #
>
> # Vendors settings live in /usr/lib/sysctl.d/.
>
> # To override a whole file, create a new file with the same in
>
> # /etc/sysctl.d/ and put new settings there. To override
>
> # only specific settings, add a file with a lexically later
>
> # name in /etc/sysctl.d/ and put new settings there.

You can search these directories for the specific settings.